# Insert a conditional in the middle of a function to give it 2 different outcomes

Tags: conditional-content

I have this function that displays a comma separated list of custom taxonomy terms.

```
<?php
$product_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'XYZ' );
// Make sure we have terms and also check for WP_Error object
if (    $product_terms
    && !is_wp_error( $product_terms )
) {
    @usort( $product_terms, function ( $a, $b )
    {
        return strcasecmp(
            $a->slug,
            $b->slug
        );
    });
    // Display your terms as normal
    $term_list = [];
    foreach ( $product_terms as $term )
        $term_list[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>';
    //$term_list[] = esc_html( $term->name );
    echo implode( ', ', $term_list );
}
?>
```

I have commented out the option to display the terms unlinked...

```
// $term_list[] = esc_html( $term->name );
```

If I uncommented the above line I'd then comment out this line...

```
$term_list[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>';
```

I'd like to insert a basic conditional that gives the option to use either of these 2 lines. e.g...

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
    $term_list[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>';
<?php } else { ?>
    $term_list[] = esc_html( $term->name );
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean, since you basically already answered your own question, as I understood it.

The only thing I see is that you should remove the  at each part of the if statement, because the code inside is also php.

```
<?php 
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $term_list[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>';
    } else {
        $term_list[] = esc_html( $term->name );
    } 
?>
```

Comment: see my next attempt in my edited answer... the IF condition works but not the ELSE statement.

Comment: Thanks, I got your fix working.. that crossed my mind just before you answered ;)

Comment: Glad to hear it works now. :)